# MS Word 365 change margin for a single line

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I am writing a screen play. I have a 1.5 inch left margin and a one inch right margin. That is the mandatory Hollywood set up. What I need to do is add a scene number every now and then just out side the left and right margins of the line indicating a new scene. I see this in the Hollywood scrips, but I have no idea how to bypass the margins for these occasional single lines of scene change information.

Comment: You can't. Maybe you can add those numbers in text boxes (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-copy-or-delete-a-text-box-4d968daa-5c86-48f2-88fa-b65871966017). Or just ask for a template to be used.

Comment: Have you tried indenting the text to the left of the margin? That seems like the simplest solution. You could even create a style just for that text. I wouldn't insert a text box as it would be harder to format consistently.

Answer (score 2):

You may insert a Text Box via the ribbon entry *Insert > Text Box*.

You may then drag the box anywhere you like on the page.

You may further define its interaction with the rest of the text by right-click,
choose "Format AutoShape/Picture", in the Layout tab.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set the body of the document as a 2-column table. The 1st column is reserved for the Scene Number. Column 2 is for the dialog.

When a Scene changes, you add a new row to the table.

Comment: Works perfectly when inserting visio diagrams into the document where I'd like the left and right margins to be minimal (0.25") and the diagram to be stretched as much as possible